# Fortran Error:Bad continuation line at (1)

Tags: unix, fortran, format

I am trying to use fortran to write a Unix script into a file. Nonetheless, it keeps reminding me that my format is incorrect. I have been doing this for many times and they are all succeed to be compiled. For this time, I do not know what goes wrong. I have attached my codes and the information on errors and I will be very grateful if someone can point out my mistakes. Thanks!!!

```
subroutine get_gmt(max1,min1,max2,min2,max3,min3,max4,min4)


        real*4 max1,min1,max2,min2,max3,min3,max4,min4
        real*4 dt1,dt2,dt3,dt4
        real*4 dtt1,dtt2,dtt3,dtt4
        dt1 = (max1-min1)/2000
        dt2 = (max1-min1)/8

        open(23,file='plot.gmt')
        write(23,100) dt1,dt2,min1,max1,min2
     &       ,max2,min3,max3,min4,max4
100          format('#!/bin/bash', /
     &         'rm tmp?.ps tmp?.cpt',//

     &         'set dt1=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set dt2=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set T1=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set T2=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set T3=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set T4=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set T5=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set T6=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set T7=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'set T8=  ',f11.5,/
     &         'psbasemap -R0/360/0/90 -JPa3/0
     &          -P -Ba40/a10 -V -X6.5 -Y24 -K > tmp.ps',/
     &         'surface data.dat -Gtmp.grd -I0.05/0.05
     &          -R -C100 -T0.35 -N10 -V',//

     &         'makecpt -Crainbow -T$T1/$T2/$dt1  -Z -V > tmp.cpt',/
     &         'makecpt -Crainbow -T$T1/$T2/$dt2 -Z -V > tmp1.cpt',//

     &         'psscale -D-1.25/1.5/3/0.4 -Ctmp1.cpt -L -O -K -A >>    tmp.ps',//
     &         'grdimage tmp.grd -R -JP -O -Ctmp.cpt -V -K >> tmp.ps',//
     &        'gawk ''{print $2,$5,0.5*$3}'' result4.dat | psxy
     &         -R -JP -K -O -B -V -Sc -N -W0.5,red >> tmp.ps',//

     &        'psxyz -R0/2/0/2/0/2 -JX2/2 -JZ2 -E135/30 -Sc0.1
     &         -W4,red -P -Gred -Bx1 -By1 -Bz1 -BWSneZ
     &         -N -X-6.0 -K -O <<END>> tmp.ps',/
     &        '0 0 1',/
     &        '0 0 0',/
     &        'END',//

     &        'pstext -R -JX -O -K -JZ -E -W4,red -P -B -N <<END>> tmp.ps',/
     &        '-0.2 0 0 9 0 15 subevent1',/
     &        '0 0 1.2 9 0 15 subevent2',/
     &        'END',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $1,$2}'' time.dat |psxy -R0/360/$T1/$T2 -JX3/3 -P -Ba60/a$dt2
     &         -V -K -O -Sc0.05 -N -X10.5 -P >> tmp.ps',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $2,$5}'' result4.dat |psxy -R
     &         -JX -K -O -B -V -Sa0.15 -N -W0.5,red
     &          >> tmp.ps',//

     &        'gmtset BASEMAP_AXES = WeSN',/
     &        'gmtset FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $1,$2}'' time1.dat |psxy
     &         -R0/90/$T1/$T2 -JX3/3 -P -Ba15/a$dt2 -V -K -O
     &         -Sc0.05 -N -X4.5 >> tmp.ps',//

     &        'psbasemap -R0/360/0/90 -JPa3/0 -P
     &         -Ba40/a10 -V -X-9 -Y-5 -K -O >> tmp.ps',/
     &        'surface data1.dat -Gtmp1.grd -I0.1/0.1 -R -C100 -T0 -N10       -V',//

     &        'makecpt -Crainbow -T$T3/$T4/$dt1 -Z -V > tmp3.cpt',//

     &        'makecpt -Crainbow -T$T3/$T4/$dt2 -Z -V > tmp4.cpt',//

     &        'psscale -D-1.25/1.5/3/0.4
     &         -Ctmp4.cpt -L -O -K -A >> tmp.ps',//

     &        'grdimage tmp1.grd -R -JP -O -Ctmp3.cpt -V -K >> tmp.ps',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $2,$5,0.5*$3}'' result4.dat |
     &         psxy -R -JP -K -O -B -V
     &         -Sc -N -W0.5,red >> tmp.ps',//

     &         'psxyz -R0/2/0/2/0/2 -JX2/2 -JZ2 -E135/30
     &         -Sc0.1 -W4,red -P -Gred -BWSneZ -Bx1 -By1
     &         -Bz1 -N -X-6.0 -K -O <<END>> tmp.ps',/
     &        '1 0 0',/
     &        '0 0 0',/
     &        'END',//

     &        'gmtset BASEMAP_AXES = WeSN',/
     &        'gmtset FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $1,$2}'' time4.dat |psxy
     &         -R0/360/$T3/$T4 -JX3/3 -P -Ba60/a$dt2 -V -K -P
     &         -Sc0.05 -N -X10.5 >> tmp.ps',//

     &        ‘gmtset BASEMAP_AXES = WeSN',/
     &        'gmtset FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $1,$2}'' time3.dat |psxy
     &         -R0/90/$T3/$T4 -JX3/3 -P -K -Ba15/a$dt2 -V
     &         -X4.5 -O -Sc0.05 -N >> tmp.ps',//

     &        'psbasemap -R0/360/0/90 -JPa3/0 -P
     &         -Ba40/a10 -V -X6.5 -Y24 -K > tmp1.ps',/
     &        'surface data2.dat -Gtmp2.grd
     &         -I0.1/0.1 -R -C100 -T0 -N10 -V',//

     &        'makecpt -Crainbow -T$T5/$T6/$dt1 -Z -V > tmp5.cpt',/
     &        'makecpt -Crainbow -T$T5/$T6/$dt2 -Z -V > tmp6.cpt',//

     &        'psscale -D-1.25/1.5/3/0.4
     &         -Ctmp6.cpt -V -K -O -A -L >> tmp1.ps',//

     &        'grdimage tmp2.grd -R -JP -O
     &         -Ctmp5.cpt -V -K >> tmp1.ps',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $2,$5,0.5*$3}'' result4.dat |psxy -R
     &         -JP -K -O -B -V -Sc -N -W0.5,red
     &         >> tmp1.ps',/
     &        'psxyz -R0/2/0/2/0/2 -JX2/2 -JZ2 -E135/30
     &         -Sc0.1 -W4,red -P -Gred -Bx1 -By1 -Bz1
     &         -BWSneZ -N -X-6.0 -K -O <<END>>tmp1.ps',/
     &        '0 1 0',/
     &        '0 0 0',/
     &        'END',//

     &        'gmtset BASEMAP_AXES = WeSN',/
     &        'gmtset FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $1,$2}'' time6.dat |psxy -R0/360/$T5/$T6
     &         -JX3/3 -P -Ba60/a$dt2 -V
     &         -X10.5 -K -O -Sc0.05 -N >> tmp1.ps',//

     &        'gmtset FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $1,$2}'' time5.dat |psxy -R0/90/$T5/$T6
     &         -JX3/3 -P -Ba15/a$dt2 -V
     &         -X4.5 -O -Sc0.05 -N -K >> tmp1.ps',//

     &        'psbasemap -R0/360/0/90 -JPa3/0 -P
     &         -Ba40/a10 -V -X-9 -Y-5 -K -O >> tmp1.ps',/
     &        'surface data3.dat -Gtmp3.grd -I0.1/0.1 -R -C100 -T0 -N10 -V',//

     &        'makecpt -Crainbow -T$T7/$T8/$dt1 -Z -V > tmp9.cpt',//

     &        'makecpt -Crainbow -T$T7/$T8/$dt2 -Z -V > tmp10.cpt',//

     &        'psscale -D-1.25/1.5/3/0.4
     &         -Ctmp10.cpt -L -O -K -A >> tmp2.ps',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $2,$5,$3}'' result4.dat |psxy
     &          -R -JP -K -O -B -V -Sc0.1 -Ctmp9.cpt -N
     &         -Gblack >> tmp2.ps',//

     &        'BASEMAP_AXES = WeSN',/
     &        'FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $2,$3}'' result4.dat |psxy
     &         -R0/360/$T7/$T8 -JX3/3 -P -Ba60/a$dt2 -V
     &         -X4.5 -K -O -Sc0.05 -N >> tmp2.ps',//

     &        'gmtset BASEMAP_AXES = WeSN',/
     &        'gmtset FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//

     &        'gawk ''{print $5,$3}'' result4.dat |psxy -R0/90/$T7/$T8
     &         -JX3/3 -P -Ba15/a$dt2 -V
     &         -X4.5 -O -Sc0.05 -N >> tmp2.ps')

        close(23)

         end
```

And it reports numerous errors, but the typical errors are as follows:

```
  &        'grdimage tmp.grd -R -JP -O -Ctmp.cpt -V -K >> tmp.ps',//
```

> Error: Positive width required in format specifier G at (1)

```
forward_modeling.f:407:6:

  &        'gmtset FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//
  1
```

> Error: Bad continuation line at (1)
>   forward_modeling.f:407:15:

```
  &        'gmtset FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 7p',//
           1
```

> Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
>   forward_modeling.f:410:6:

```
  &         -JX3/3 -P -Ba15/a$dt2 -V
  1
```

> Error: Bad continuation line at (1)
>   Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

```
forward_modeling.f:285:72:

  &       ,max2,min3,max3,min4,max4
                                                                    1
```

> Error: FORMAT label 100 at (1) not defined

Comment: That's one ugly abuse of a format statement.  Assuming fixed-form source code from the .f file extension, you need to make sure the continuation marker '&' is in column 6.  If there are tab characters in the code, those are invalid and should be replaced with spaces.  Line lengths should not exceed 72 characters.  If a line does exceed 72 characters, then it may be silently truncated.  Finally, a statement can be continued for only 255 lines.  I haven't bother counting your lines.  Try constructing your bash script with strings.

Comment: I have to go this way because I want to plot a graph which will use the max and min values passing to the function. The problem might be too long statement. I will try to break down the statement and write it into two files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @evets: the posted code is 171 lines, and the (huge) format statement somewhat less. Junjie: You wouldn't need to write multiple files, just a sequence of writes to the one file. The standard only allows 72 char per line in fixed-form but many compilers have an option to increase it; you don't say which you are using. Also your posted line 89 `‘gmtset BASEMAP_AXES = WeSN',/` has a Unicode left single quote, meretricously called a 'smart' quote by Microsoft, not a standard (ASCII) single quote. Also, you can't set variables in bash the way you are trying.

Comment: @junjie liu, you do not have to go that way.   You can use strings to construct the output and write those strings into the file.  By abusing the format statement in the manner that you do, you are setting yourself for problems.  Otherwise, you wouldn't need to ask for help here.